# What is the point in using typedef to declare a functon?

Tags: c++, function, typedef

I am a bit confused about why I can use `typedef` to declare functions. Here is my example:

```
int Add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int Mult(int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
}


typedef int func(int, int);


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    func Add;
    cout << Add(5, 57) << endl;

}
```

What is the point above int `func Add;` While I can call `Add()` directly?

- Can someone explain a scenario where I should use typedef on functions?

Comment: You can use it later to pass a pointer to this function somewhere: `void foo(func * p_func)` instead of `void foo(int (* p_func)(int, int))` or `func * foo(void)` instead of `void ( * foo(void) )(int, int)` In general typedefs allow to simplify gibberish declarations like `char ( & ( foo_t::* [1] ) (foo_t( * )[2]) & )[3]` and to give semantic meaning.

Comment: Re: “What is the point ...” — no idea.

Comment: In this code there is no point.  In other code it is used as a way to make writing code easier like declaring function pointers.

Comment: @VTT — yes, but if the point is to pass a pointer, the typedef should be defined as a pointer.

Comment: As a rule, typedefs exist to give recurring things a useful name. Giving a name to a signature can be useful in e.g. declaring `std::function<func>`. Or as mentioned, it can be used to pass a plain old pointer, but *without* hiding pointer semantics behind an alias. If you seek consistency with the same advice for object pointers, this may be up your alley.

Comment: Nowadays you should consider replacing typedefs with `using` declarations, by the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, this `typedef` is completely useless here.

But it could make sense if `Add()` would be defined in another compilation unit.  The main benefit would then to provide a predefined fonction signature that you would use a lot.  You could then use it in the second compilation unit to declare `Add()` either at local level of a function using it (your example) or at global level.

This being said, a more modern way to express the same would be:

```
using func = int (int, int);    //instead of typedef
```

A more interesting use case for this feature is when you have a lot of functions that are intended to be interchangeable, and that you want to pass as a parameter which one to use:

```
void test(int a, int b, func f) {
    cout << f(a, b) << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    test (5, 57, Add);
    test (18,2,Mult);
    test (15,12, [](int a, int b)->int { return 2*a-b; });
}
```

But if you like doing this, consider the alternative of using `std::function<int(int,int)>` :  this is more powerful.  It could allow you to pass any kind of callables as arguments, such as a callable object rather than a function:

```
class X {
    int c; 
public: 
X (int c=0) : c(c) {};
int operator()(int a, int b) { return 2*a+b+c; }    
};

X g(2);  // g is an object of class x, intialised with 2
test (18,2,g);  // does work with function but not with simple typedef
```

Answer (score 3):

I can think of only application of that, however, I have never seen it in use.

An example could be an implementation name hiding. Imagine you have a library function, and this function which has to be inlineable, so you provide it's implementation in the header file. It also needs to call other functions. So your library header file (`library.h`)might look like that:

```
inline int do_stuff() {
    int a = do_internal_stuff1(10, 15, 25);
    int b = do_internal_stuff2(10, 15, 25);
    return a + b;
}
```

In order for that to work, declaration of `do_internal_stuff` functions should be 
visible, so you end up in including `internal_stuff.h`, which declares those two functions. But now they are callable in any file which includes `library.h`, and you might not want this.

One reason to avoid including `internal_stuff.h` would be delcaring functions locally:

```
inline int do_stuff() {
    int do_internal_stuff1(int, int, int);
    int do_internal_stuff2(int, int, int);
    int a = do_internal_stuff1(10, 15, 25);
    int b = do_internal_stuff2(10, 15, 25);
    return a + b;
}
```

If you have 20 `do_internal_stuff` functions, it could become a bit tedious. Than you might want to

```
inline int do_stuff() {
    typedef int internal_func(int, int, int);
    internal_func do_internal_stuff1, do_internal_stuff2, ...;
    int a = do_internal_stuff1(10, 15, 25);
    int b = do_internal_stuff2(10, 15, 25);
    return a + b;
}
```

Please note, I am not advocating for any code like this. I am merely playing devils advocate to answer the question *why do it*.

Comment: Thank you! One thing: "If you have 20 do_internal_stuff functions, it could become a bit tedious. ": I can use this type alias as a pointer to function and make it the type of a vector then I can push pointers to functions:   `std::vector<func*> vpFn{20}; vpFn[0] = Add; vpFn[1] = Mult; cout << vpFn[0](10, 56) << endl; cout << vpFn[1](10, 56) << endl;`.